# How to align colon (:) in two column mode?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

[image]

How can I align the colon horizontally in a two-column mode like the above figure?

I want to use it in an `itemize` environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore my previous suggestion, here are the modified tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{$\bullet$\enskip}>{\fontshape{it}\selectfont}l@{:\enskip}X@{}}
Some thing & How to align in two column mode blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \\
Some thing & How to align in two column mode blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\\
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

PS: I am using standard tags as you are not providing any `MWE`

Comment: This gets rid of the dot before each item.

Comment: @Tvde1 Please ignore my previous suggestion, apologize for that, now the answer is edited....thanks for point out this...